# SwiftUI List Selection Binding and onChange

Tags: list, swiftui

I have a List with a selection binding and need to run a function when the user changes the selection in the list. The issue is that if I use onChange(of: myVar) it runs after the section has been changed, whereas I need to run it prior to the selection change taking place because I am updating a view with a bunch of values based on the selection in the list.

Here's what I need to have happen:

1. User selects on or more items in the list
2. resetSelection is run
3. List selection is updated

Here's what the List looks like with an onChange (again, this does not work).

```
List(selection: $mySet) {
    ForEach(mySet.compactMap { $0 }, id: \.self) { item in
        Text(item.name)
    }
}
.onChange(of: mySet) { _ in
    resetSelection()
}
```

Because the onChange is running after mySet is changed, the app crashes with an out of range error because the values for one item in the list may not match the values of a different item in the list.

A partial example of the view that is using the values set by resetSelection is:

```
struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Picker("", selection: $endNum.animation()) {
            if let totalPages = mySet.first?.totalPages {
                ForEach(startNum...totalPages, id: \.self) { option in
                    Text("\(option)")
                        .tag(option)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I'm thinking about this incorrectly, and there's a better way to handle this please let me know. I need to use List selection so that can't go away.

Comment: You're ignoring the changed value by using `_`. Pass that value (which is what it will change to) into your functions like `resetSelection`

Comment: Nope. Just tried onChange(of: mySet) { selection in resetSelection() } and it still crashes. The function doesn't need any values, it's just updating the variables. I'm fairly certain the issue is that the selection is changing before the onChange runs and the view crashes because of it.

Comment: You'd need to show a [mre] then. Clearly something _does_ need values if it is crashing with index out of range.

Comment: Just updated with a small example of where the main issue is. startNum and totalPages set the range and if the resetSelection function hasn't run (finished running) before the selection in the List changes, the app crashes with out of range.

Comment: Using `startNum...totalPages` and `.self` in the `ForEach` is very dangerous and not at all the recommended way to use a `ForEach` -- you should use `Identifiable` data. Watch Demystify SwiftUI from WWDC. I'd post an answer, but without a [mre], it's not possible to provide concrete code.

Answer (score 0):

The answer ended up being simpler than I thought. Instead of the closed range using an @Published variable, I added to the if let to ensure the new value was being used instead.

```
Picker("", selection: $endNum.animation()) {
    if let totalPages = mySet.first?.totalPages,
       let startPage = mySet.first?.startPage {
        ForEach(startPage...totalPages, id: \.self) { option in
            Text("\(option)")
                .tag(option)
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps someone else!

Comment: This is unsafe and not guaranteed to work consistently, since you're lying to the system and telling it that the items are identified by their indices (which they aren't)

Comment: I'm sorry but I believe you are wrong. If you have a suggestion, please let me know. AFAIK there is no reason you can't create a ForEach with integers as a closed range. Also, I have been thoroughly testing and so far it works 100% of the time because of the if let ensuring it has the correct values. However, I, like most everyone, do not know everything and am always open to helpful answers.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the closed range as long as the contents doesn’t change. Any time you provide an id, it should correspond to a unique element. It may be working for you here, but it should not be relied on as a safe practice for future visitors to this site. See Demystify SwiftUI from WWDC for a more in depth explanation of identity in SwiftUI.